# Exporting data to a excel with a Limit condition using Iron Python

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to export the data to excel by specifying the limit condition in Iron Python script. When the Action Control - Button is clicked, then the data that satisfies the limit condition should be exported to excel. Below is the code  which is writing the complete data to excel even though the limit condition is specified.

Please assist me in limiting the data that is being exported to excel.

Thank you beforehand for the clarification.

#

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers
from System.IO import File, Directory
from System.Collections.Generic import List

# directory
if not Directory.Exists("C:\Users\47586\Documents\Daily activities\POC"):
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\47586\Documents\Daily 
activities\POC")
if Document.Data.Tables["Test"].Columns["Sales"] > 200:
               table = Document.ActiveDataTableReference
               names = ['Country_Name','Sales']
               allRows = 
Document.Data.AllRows.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet()
               writer = 
Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsDataWriter)
# columns
               stream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\47586\Documents\Daily 
activities\POC\Filename.xls")


               allColumnNames = List[str]()
               writer.Write(stream, table, allRows,names)
               stream.Close()
               stream.Dispose()
#######################################################################
```

Thanks
San

Comment: the reason it's exporting the entire table is because you are writing the data table to the file instead of the visualization. I don't have the time right now to help you with the code but thought I'd point you to the solution, and if I get a minute later I'll come back with a proper answer :)

Comment: Thanks Niko, The below code worked..

Answer (score 0):

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers
from System.IO import File, Directory
table = Document.Data.Tables["Test"]
rowSelection=table.Select("Sales=200")
#Limiting and Column Declaration
names = ['Customer_Name','Sales']
allRows = rowSelection.AsIndexSet()
writer = 
Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsDataWriter)
stream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\Desktop\export.xls")
allColumnNames = List[str]()
writer.Write(stream, table, allRows,names)
stream.Close()
stream.Dispose()
```